# Meteor build process creates unwanted dist folder

Tags: meteor, npm

Recently my meteor build (npm install) creates a 'dist' folder. I don't want this behaviour, especially since it includes code from my 'private' folder, which winds up causing all kinds of problems.

How do I stop the 'dist' folder from beiing built?
I am developing on Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow David. Meteor is open source, so you can look at how the build system works and make the changes yourself, and even do a pull request if you think everyone else wants that feature. Alternatively you could make sure that one of your scripts cleans out the dist folder after deploying to your server.

Comment: If you know what specifically is creating the 'dist' folder that would be helpful.

I spent 3 weeks debugging mup deploy, which also just stopped working, and learning about things I have already forgotten once they ceased being a problem.
I don't really enjoy getting distracted for weeks on end with some sudden opaque-to-me change to the framework's behavior.

Comment: I don't know what creates that folder. I presume that it's a necessary part of the build process, which probably can't be deleted. Mup has it's own tag on stack overflow, and it actively maintained - have you posted a question here about that problem?

Comment: The dist directory may have something to do with babel, and may be a side-effect of configuring babel (needed to support ES6 syntax in a portion of my project).